# ¿Cómo agregar una variable js del mes actual en Angular?

Tags: angular

No tengo tanta experiencia con Angular o Typescript, hasta ahorita el proyecto que llevo necesito que indique "Libros del mes de__________" y en el espacio en blanco colocar el mes actual pero no sé como agregarlo.

Intenté esto en mi componente inicio.html:

```html
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 my-4">
                    <h6 class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size: x-large;">LIBROS SUGERIDOS DEL MES <script>const monthNames = ["ENERO", "FEBRERO", "MARZO", "ABRIL", "MAYO", "JUNIO",
                        "JULIO", "AGOSTO", "SEPTIEMBRE", "OCTUBRE", "NOVIEMBRE", "DICIEMBRE"
                      ];
                      
                      const d = new Date();
                      document.write("DE " + monthNames[d.getMonth()]);</script></h6>
                    <hr class="linea1">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Funciona en Javascript pero no sé como hacer que funcione en Angular. Estoy usando la versión de Angular CLI 9.0.6, Node 12.16.1

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia, me temo: necesitas entender lo que es un componente de Angular y cómo funcionan las plantillas (templates) en los componentes para generar el HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Angular el código js va en el archivo ts del componente.

**archivo .ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

const monthNames = [
  "ENERO",
  "FEBRERO",
  "MARZO",
  "ABRIL",
  "MAYO",
  "JUNIO",
  "JULIO",
  "AGOSTO",
  "SEPTIEMBRE",
  "OCTUBRE",
  "NOVIEMBRE",
  "DICIEMBRE"
];

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  // iniciar variable con el nombre del mes actual
  // esta variable se mostrará en la vista
  mesActual = monthNames[new Date().getMonth()];
}
```

**archivo .html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 my-4">
        <h6 class="font-weight-bold" style="font-size: x-large;">
           LIBROS SUGERIDOS DEL MES {{mesActual}}
        </h6>
        <hr class="linea1">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r6vpes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Adicionalmente para obtener el mes actual sin usar un arreglo de meses se puede hacer así:

```js
mesActual = new Date().toLocaleString("default", { month: "long" });

console.log(mesActual);
```

Comment: Me funciona con el arreglo, según la lógica es definir todo el arreglo en el .ts y aplicarlo en el .html, muy agradecida porque ya entendí un poco mejor.